# HTML email doesn't work

Tags: php, email, smtp, sendmail

I am submitting a form which inserts record into database and then sends email to the specified address. The below code doesn't working for me. i'm getting errors.

```
if (isset($_POST['submit'])) {

//if (
//  !empty($_POST['item_cid']) && 
//  !empty($_POST['item_code']) && 
//  !empty($_POST['item_name']) && 
//  !empty($_POST['item_price']) && 
//  !empty($_POST['item_qty']) &&

//  is_array($_POST['item_cid']) &&
//  is_array($_POST['item_code']) &&
//  is_array($_POST['item_name']) &&
//  is_array($_POST['item_price']) &&
//  is_array($_POST['item_qty']) &&
//  count($_POST['item_cid']) === count($_POST['item_code'])
//  )

//{

foreach($_POST['item_cid'] as $key => $value) {
//Data for Orders Table
    $cid = mysqli_real_escape_string($connection,$value);
    $pcode = mysqli_real_escape_string($connection,$_POST['item_code'][$key]);
    $pname = mysqli_real_escape_string($connection,$_POST['item_name'][$key]);
    $pprice = mysqli_real_escape_string($connection,$_POST['item_price'][$key]);
    $pqty = mysqli_real_escape_string($connection,$_POST['item_qty'][$key]);

//Data for Customers Table
    $cname = mysqli_real_escape_string($connection,$_POST['item_cname'][$key]);
    $cemail = mysqli_real_escape_string($connection,$_POST['item_cemail'][$key]);
    $cphone = mysqli_real_escape_string($connection,$_POST['item_cphone'][$key]);
    $caddress = mysqli_real_escape_string($connection,$_POST['item_caddress'][$key]);
    $ctotal = mysqli_real_escape_string($connection,$_POST['item_ctotal'][$key]);


//    $sql = "INSERT INTO orders (cid, ordprod_code, ordprod_name, ordprod_price, ordprod_qty) VALUES ('$value', '$pcode', '$pname', '$pprice', '$pqty')";
//    $sql2 = "INSERT INTO customers (cid, cname, cemail, cphone, caddress, ctotal) VALUES ('$value','$cname','$cemail','$cphone','$caddress','$ctotal')";
    if ($connection->query($sql) === TRUE) {
        echo "Orders record created successfully \n";
    }
//     } else {
//        echo "Error: " . $sql . "<br>" . $connection->error;
//     }

    if ($connection->query($sql2) === TRUE) {
        echo "Customers record created successfully \n";
    }
//    } else {
//        echo "Error: " . $sql2 . "<br>" . $connection->error;
    } // close the loop

//********************************
// START EMAIL FUNCTION
//********************************

// PREPARE THE BODY OF THE MESSAGE

$message = '<html><body>';
$message .= '<img src="http://example.com/static/images/emailhead.jpg" alt="OMREL JEWELRY" />';
$message .= '<h3>Customer Information:</h3>';
$message .= '<table rules="all" style="border-color: #666;" cellpadding="10">';
$message .= '<tr><td><strong>Name:</strong></td><td>'. strip_tags($_POST['item_cname']) .'</td></tr>';
$message .= '<tr><td><strong>Email:</strong></td><td>'. strip_tags($_POST['item_cemail']) .'</td></tr>';
$message .= '<tr><td><strong>Phone:</strong></td><td>'. strip_tags($_POST['item_cphone']) .'</td></tr>';
$message .= '<tr><td><strong>Address:</strong> </td><td>'. strip_tags($_POST['item_caddress']) .'</td></tr>';
$message .= '</table>';
$message .= '</body></html>';

//  MAKE SURE THE "FROM" EMAIL ADDRESS DOESN'T HAVE ANY NASTY STUFF IN IT
$pattern = "/^[_a-z0-9-]+(\.[_a-z0-9-]+)*@[a-z0-9-]+(\.[a-z0-9-]+)*(\.[a-z]{2,3})$/i"; 
    if (preg_match($pattern, $_POST['item_cemail'])) { 
        $cleanedFrom = $_POST['item_cemail']; 
    } else { 
    return "The email address you entered was invalid. Please try again!";
    } 

//   CHANGE THE BELOW VARIABLES TO YOUR NEEDS
$to = 'info@domain.com';
$subject = 'New order Arrived CustomerID #'.$cid.' ';
$headers = "From: " . $cleanedFrom . "\r\n";
$headers .= "Reply-To: ".strip_tags($_POST['item_ceamil']) ."\r\n";
$headers .= "MIME-Version: 1.0\r\n";
$headers .= "Content-Type: text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1\r\n";

if (mail($to, $subject, $message, $headers)) {
echo 'Your order has been sent. Our sales department will contact you soon...';
} else {
echo 'There was a problem sending the email.';
}

print_r($_POST['item_cname']);


} // Data Inserted & Emailed Close IF Statement

session_destroy();
```

**The HTML**

```
<p class="form-row">
        <label class="" for="item_cname[]">Your Name <span class="required">*</span></lable>
        <input class="input-text" type="text" name="item_cname[]" placeholder="Your Name" />
        </p>
<p class="form-row">
        <label class="" for="item_cemail[]">Email Address <span class="required">*</span></lable>
        <input type="text" name="item_cemail[]"  placeholder="Your Email Address"/>
        </p>
<p class="form-row">
        <label class="" for="item_cphone[]">Phone Number <span class="required">*</span></lable>
        <input type="text" name="item_cphone[]"  placeholder="Your Phone Number"/>
        </p>
<p class="form-row">
        <label class="" for="item_caddress[]">Address <span class="required">*</span></lable>
        <textarea name="item_caddress[]"  placeholder="Your Address" class="input-text" rows="2" cols="2" maxlength="140"></textarea>
        </p>
```

**The Errors**

> Notice: Undefined variable: sql in /home/public_html/dev/process.php
>   on line 48
>
> Warning: mysqli::query(): Empty query in
>   /home/public_html/dev/process.php on line 48
>
> Notice: Undefined variable: sql2 in /home/public_html/dev/process.php
>   on line 55
>
> Warning: mysqli::query(): Empty query in
>   /home/public_html/dev/process.php on line 55
>
> Warning: strip_tags() expects parameter 1 to be string, array given in
>   /home/public_html/dev/process.php on line 72
>
> Warning: strip_tags() expects parameter 1 to be string, array given in
>   /home/public_html/dev/process.php on line 73
>
> Warning: strip_tags() expects parameter 1 to be string, array given in
>   /home/public_html/dev/process.php on line 74
>
> Warning: strip_tags() expects parameter 1 to be string, array given in
>   /home/public_html/dev/process.php on line 75
>
> Warning: preg_match() expects parameter 2 to be string, array given in
>   /home/public_html/dev/process.php on line 81

All those errors pointing towards the `strip_tags($_POST['item_*'])` (the * represents the name of item).

How to fix this?

Comment: It would help if you told us what line / which of the strip_tags() are causing this error, since you aren't showing us what / where you are setting the $_POST data, we don't know what they contain.

Comment: You are adding `$_POST` to `strip_tags()` this way `strip_tags($_POST['item_cname'])` when its array not string.

Comment: You just need to check if the Posted value is not null AND is string, as the error clearly says that strip_tags function needs string ONLY

Comment: Can you give the html from where you are submitting?

Comment: Ok, i have updated my question with html & errors with line numbers

Comment: @SanjayKumarNS updated my question. please check

Comment: @Puneet data is not null, can you give me some code example?

Comment: @Testing Then how to do the strip part?

Comment: Probably you only need `$_POST['item_cname']` @yaqoob

Comment: @Testing i did that, now those errors are replaced with these `Notice: Array to string conversion`

Comment: Explain complete error please @yaqoob

Comment: Probably only this: edit this portion only first and give results: `if (preg_match($pattern, $_POST['item_cemail'])) { 
        $cleanedFrom = $_POST['item_cemail']; 
    }`

Comment: @Testing i'm going to update my question with full code.

Comment: @Testing please check my updated PHP code...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Are you looking for this. If yes, this should work for you:

```
<?php 
if (isset($_POST['submit'])) { 
foreach($_POST['item_cid'] as $key => $value) { 
//Data for Orders Table 
$cid = mysqli_real_escape_string($connection,$value); 
$pcode = mysqli_real_escape_string($connection,$_POST['item_code'][$key]); 
$pname = mysqli_real_escape_string($connection,$_POST['item_name'][$key]); 
$pprice = mysqli_real_escape_string($connection,$_POST['item_price'][$key]); 
$pqty = mysqli_real_escape_string($connection,$_POST['item_qty'][$key]); 

//Data for Customers Table 
$cname = mysqli_real_escape_string($connection,$_POST['item_cname'][$key]); 
$cemail = mysqli_real_escape_string($connection,$_POST['item_cemail'][$key]); 
$cphone = mysqli_real_escape_string($connection,$_POST['item_cphone'][$key]); 
$caddress = mysqli_real_escape_string($connection,$_POST['item_caddress'][$key]); 
$ctotal = mysqli_real_escape_string($connection,$_POST['item_ctotal'][$key]); 

if ($connection->query($sql) === TRUE) { 
echo "Orders record created successfully \n"; 
} 

if ($connection->query($sql2) === TRUE) { 
echo "Customers record created successfully \n"; 
} 
} 

$message = '<html><body>'; 
$message .= '<img src="http://example.com/static/images/emailhead.jpg" alt="OMREL JEWELRY" />'; 
$message .= '<h3>Customer Information:</h3>'; 
$message .= '<table rules="all" style="border-color: #666;" cellpadding="10">'; 
$message .= '<tr><td><strong>Name:</strong></td><td>'. $cname .'</td></tr>'; 
$message .= '<tr><td><strong>Email:</strong></td><td>'. $cemail .'</td></tr>'; 
$message .= '<tr><td><strong>Phone:</strong></td><td>'. $cphone .'</td></tr>'; 
$message .= '<tr><td><strong>Address:</strong></td><td>'. $ctotal .'</td></tr>'; 
$message .= '</table>'; 
$message .= '</body></html>'; 

$pattern = "/^[_a-z0-9-]+(\.[_a-z0-9-]+)*@[a-z0-9-]+(\.[a-z0-9-]+)*(\.[a-z]{2,3})$/i"; 
if (preg_match($pattern, $cemail)) { 
$cleanedFrom = $cemail; 
} else { 
return "The email address you entered was invalid. Please try again!"; 
} 

$to = 'info@example.com'; 
$subject = 'New order Arrived CustomerID #'.$cid.' '; 
$headers = "From: " . $cleanedFrom . "\r\n"; 
$headers .= "Reply-To: ".strip_tags($_POST['item_ceamil']) ."\r\n"; 
$headers .= "MIME-Version: 1.0\r\n"; 
$headers .= "Content-Type: text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1\r\n"; 

if (mail($to, $subject, $message, $headers)) { 
echo 'Your order has been sent. Our sales department will contact you soon...'; 
} else { 
echo 'There was a problem sending the email.'; 
} 

print_r($_POST['item_cname']); 


} // Data Inserted & Emailed Close IF Statement 

session_destroy(); 
?>
```

Answer (score 0):

Probably one of your post data is array object.
Try to make print_r($_POST[xxx]) to check your POST values.
Strip Tags function parameter should not be an array object.